# Preventing Ubuntu upgrade to switch the storage driver from Overlay2 to aufs for docker container

Tags: drivers, upgrade, docker, storage

I am upgrading an old server which is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 22.04.3 LTS, going first from 18.04 to 20.04 and then to 22.04 LTS.

The old server with 18.04 has some docker container that uses the storage driver overlay2 on extfs as backing filesystem. When upgrading 18.04 LTS to 20.04.6 LTS, the upgrade switches the storage driver to aufs which is in turn not supported anymore on 22.04.03 LTS and stops the upgrade process.
So how can I prevent the intermediate upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 from switching the storage driver for docker container?
Thank you for any hint.
Tobias

Comment: Are you saying there is no upgrade path from Docker on 18.04 to Docker on 22.04? I don't think that is the case. Unless Docker on 22.04 would restart support for the overlay2 driver (which I think it doesn't), I don't see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, I just want the storage driver to stay as it is. In the original state on 18.04 it is set to overlay2. After the update to 20.04, it is unnecessarily changed to Aufs. This prevents an upgrade to 22.04, as Aufs is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing further the issue, got the solution. The Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS installs an additional parallel instance of docker through snap and migrates the containers. The initial docker installed through apt remains on the server but not responsive when running `sudo docker info`. After I uninstalled docker through snap `sudo snap remove docker` the initial docker installation got active with the right storage driver.

I figured out when inspecting the output of `sudo docker info` and `sudo systemctl status docker`: the snap version saves the writeable layers in

**/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker**

while the apt version saves it in

**/var/lib/docker**